# 'Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded' error throwing in Phonegap iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

i have developed an iPhone app using Phonegap 2.9 and Jquery mobile 1.4 Beta 1. The application run fine in Xcode iPhone simulator, but throws 'Channel not fired: onDOMContentLoaded' in cordova.js when i tried to deploy to iPhone device (iOS 6) from Xcode.

The app takes long time (above 2-3 min) to show index.html and shows the above error in Xcode output window.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are not including any external javascript files that cannot be accessed from your device. Also check the network connection on the device.

Does the app download a large amount of data or make any slow\large requests on startup?  I get the problem occasionally when a request times out, or the connection drops out.